# $A, B$ closed of compact metric space $X$, $A \subsetneq B$ then $f_n(A) \subsetneq f_n(B)$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ compact metric space, $D=\{x_n: n \in \mathbb{N} \} $ a countable dense subset of $X$. For all n, let $f_n:X \rightarrow [0,1]$ defined by $$f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+d(x_n,x)}$$

Prove exista $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that for all $A, B$ closed subsets of $X$ such that $A \subsetneq B$ then $f_n(A) \subsetneq f_n(B)$

If $f_n(A)=f_n(B)$, exist $a \in A, b \in B$ such that $d(x_n, a) =d(x_n, b) $ if we prove $b \in B \setminus A$ and $d(a, b) =0$ we finish but its no clear for me. Could you give a hint for this or other form to solve it?

Comment: Exactly, but I have problems because I have $f_n(A) \subset f_n(B)$ but not proper. This is the reason I tried by contradiction

Comment: This is not true. Suppose, for example, that $X = [0, 3]$ (under the usual metric on $\Bbb{R}$), $A = [0, 1]$, and $B = [2, 3]$. Let $x_n$ enumerate $\Bbb{Q} \cap [0, 3]$. Then, for some $n$, we have $x_n = 1.5$, and $f_n(A) = f_n(B) = [2/5, 2/3]$. Is there some error in transcribing the question?

Comment: You are right, I have already edit the question

Comment: That also seems wrong. I doubt there is an $n$ that works for *all* closed sets $A$ and $B$. One could come up with a counterexample on the sphere in $\Bbb{R}^2$, for example; for any given $x_n$, we could construct singleton sets $A$ and $B$ that are equidistant from $x_n$.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, the question is wrong and a counter-example can be constructed
as follows.

Let $(X,d)=([0,1],d)$, where $d(x,y)=|x-y|$. Let $D=\mathbb{Q}\cap X$.
Fix an enumeration $D=\{x_{n}\mid n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ for $D$. Let
$A=\{0\}$ and $B=\{0,1\}$. Clearly, $A$ and $B$ are closed, and
$A\subsetneq B$. Choose $n$ such that $x_{n}=\frac{1}{2}$. Note
that $f_{n}(A)=f_{n}(B)=\{\frac{2}{3}\}$.

---

It seems that the question should be rephrased as: For any closed
subsets $A,B\subseteq X$ with $A\subsetneq B$, there exists $n$
such that $f_{n}(A)\subsetneq f_{n}(B).$

Proof: We consider the case that $A\neq\emptyset$. Choose $b\in B\setminus A$.
Since $A$ is closed, $d(b,A):=\inf\{d(b,x)\mid x\in A\}>0$. Let
$r=\frac{1}{2}d(b,A)>0$. We go to show that there exists $n$ such
that $f_{n}(b)\notin f_{n}(A)$ by contradiction. Suppose the contrary
that for each $n$, $f_{n}(b)\in f_{n}(A)$, then there exists $a_{n}\in A$
such that $f_{n}(b)=f_{n}(a_{n})$. Therefore, $d(x_{n},b)=d(x_{n},a_{n})>r$.
Since $D$ is dense in $X$, this is impossible!

Comment: Thank you so much.